# (wx)Maxima: how to iterate an action over every member of a list?

Tags: list, maxima, wxmaxima

I'm wondering if there is a functional way to apply an action to every element of list, in Maxima, without necessarily looping over the list?

e.g. if I would like to remove every element of the list `a:[1,2,3]` from the list `b:[5,4,3,2,1]`. Obviously, something like:

```
f(a,b):=
block(
[aList:a, newList:b],
for k thru length(aList)
do newList: delete(aList[k],newList) 
);
```

I just wondered if there was a more direct way? I thought `apply` might work, but couldn't figure it out, as it seems to take the whole list as the argument (vs. list elements).

Comment: By the way, about the general topic of iterating without an explicit loop, take a look at `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways to accomplish that. One way is to treat the arguments as sets and apply `setdifference`.

```
(%i2) a: [1, 2, 3] $              

(%i3) b: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] $

(%i4) setify(a);
(%o4)                       {1, 2, 3}
(%i5) setify(b);
(%o5)                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
(%i6) setdifference (setify(b), setify(a));
(%o6)                        {4, 5}
(%i7) listify(%);
(%o7)                        [4, 5]
```

That works if `a` and `b` are really sets, i.e. order doesn't matter, and elements are unique.

Another way:

```
(%i8) sublist (b, lambda ([x], not member(x, a)));
(%o8)                        [5, 4]
```

I guess the `sublist` approach makes fewer assumptions, so it is more generally applicable.

Comment: Would you recommend the same approach in the case of, e.g., evaluating a predicate for all elements of a list? For example, if one wanted to determine whether every value in a list `a` was equal to 1, then something like `asublist:sublist(a, lambda([e], is(equal(e,1))))` then compare `length(a)` to `length(asublist)`? I find myself needing conditional logic that depends on the combination of predicates of list items quite a bit and am trying to work out simple / direct methods of implementing this. If this is quite different, I'll post a separate question :)

Comment: In that case what you want is `every`. See also `some`. Sometimes it's helpful to work in two steps, first compute true/false for each item and then see if they are all/some/none equal to true. That would be `foo: map(P, L)` where P is a predicate and L is a list, and then `every(identity, foo)`. NB. `map`, `every`, and `some` can all handle functions with two or more arguments, there are examples shown in the reference manual.